# How To calculate raster land cover inside overlapping buffer zones?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator

I am working with a raster land cover file that consists of several  land cover types (e.g. forest, buildings, grass ect.) in total there is 40 different land cover types.

I have 1200 bufferzonen (vector file) each on 500 meters. I would like, for each bufferzone (they have all a unik_ID) to calculate how many square meters that consist land cover type 1 (forst), 2 (buildings), 3 (grass) ect.

Some buffer zones are overlapping....

In the end I would like one crosstable that contains all the 1200 bufferzones and the square meters of each landcover type inside all the buffers.

I´m using ModelBuilder.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  Are you more comfortable with raster or vector analysis?  I ask one or other dataset will need to be converted so that both are raster or both are vector - and I would do the latter.

Comment: I am using ArcMap v. 10

Comment: I've tried to do it in vector, but my land cover file is so large that clip and other tools will not work in vector .. Therefore, I would like to try raster analysis, but have no experience with it

Comment: Have you tried using the [**Clip**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009n000000) tool from the Raster toolset on your Land Cover raster with just one of your vector buffers as a **clipping_geometry**?  If that works then you can probably iterate through the buffers and do the same to each of them.